# Adding styles to R Markdown File

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here's my code. Just an example really.

```
##Data
###This is the table where we can display stuff. Easy to do.
Test Table | Second header
-------    | -------
cell 1     | _cell 2_
cell 3     | cell 4
```

I want to some divs maybe with classes attached so I can just make my own CSS file. But I don't even know how to do that or where to start. I've done some researching but couldn't find much on the great Google. Then I realized I'd have to accomplish another task of adding the stylesheet to the HTML file in a `<link>` tag.

My three questions

- How do I link a stylesheet in R Markdown HTML files.
- Is there a way to add something like `<div class=container>` in R
  Markdown.
- And can I add styles straight in my .rmd file?

Comment: You can add custom `.css` files using the css option - see the **Custom CSS** section of [this link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JasonAizkalns , figured it out.

```
---
title: "Test Page"
output:
html_document:
theme: journal
---
```

With the options as following for theme :

"default", "cerulean", "journal", "flatly", "readable", "spacelab", "united", "cosmo"